# Merge 2 HTML Pages into One

Tags: javascript, html

I have a webpage with called `page1.html` with button `A`

I would like to show `page2.html` on the same page when button `A` is clicked without creating a new file.

Is there anyway to do this?

Comment: it means you want to load external file in same page where clicked

Comment: yea is there anyway to do this?

Comment: Why would you want to do that anyway? You could include the contents of the second html(the one where you don't want to create the file) in the same html file and populate the main container based on the button click.

Comment: @Aditya how would i go about doing that?

Comment: @Jonathan check out my answre

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can manage it with CSS and Javascript using an `iframe` tag, [here's a demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/14pj2m1t/) :

**HTML:**

```
<input type="button" onclick="showPage()" value="show"/>
<iframe id="page2" src="http://jsfiddle.net/">
</iframe>
```

**CSS:**

```
#page2{
  width:400px;
  heigth:800px;
  display:none;
}
```

**JS:**

```
function showPage(){
console.log("ok");
var page2=document.getElementById("page2");
if(page2.style.display=="none")
    page2.style.display="block";
else 
    page2.style.display="none";
}
```

***EDIT:***

According to what I understood from one of your comments, if you want to have the HTML code in the same page then you just have to use a `div` instead of an `iframe` and show it, see [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/14pj2m1t/1/).

```
<div id="page2" >
  <p>This is an iframe containing new page</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to learn JavaScript to manage such action.

Here is a way how to do this... just one solution.

http://clicklinks.be/tutorials/javascript/prototype/page-loading/

I hope this is a start.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.